# Is "*p = ++(*q)" undefined when p and q point to the same object?

Tags: c, c99, operator-precedence, sequence-points

after reading about sequence points, I learned that `i = ++i` is undefined.

So how about this code:

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
int *q = &i;
 *p = ++(*q);           // that should also be undefined right?
```

Let's say if initialization of p and q depends on some (complicated) condition.
And they may be pointing to same object like in above case.
What will happen? If it is undefined, what tools can we use to detect?

Edit: If two pointers are not supposed to point to same object, can we use C99 restrict?
Is it what 'strict' mean?

Comment: A bloody good question! +1 from me... hmmm....

Comment: Why is `i = ++i;` undefined? The compiler must fetch some value from the RHS expression to do the assignment and the preincrement operator will always return the stored value incremented by 1, so the result should be predictable. If it were `i = i++;` then it would be undefined.

Comment: @Praetorian : Its undefined. See: Chapter 5: Point 4: <quote>Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression</quote>

Comment: @Praetorian: By my understanding of the rules, `i=i=i+1;` would be undefined because it writes a variable twice without an intervening sequence point.  Beyond that, I believe that if `i` is not volatile, a compiler may evaluate `x=++y` by computing y+1, storing it to x (for the assignment operator), and then later incrementing y.  On some processors, the above sequence would take three instructions, the minimum possible for `x=++y;`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is undefined behavior -- you have two modifications of an object without a sequence point between them.  Unfortunately, checking for this automatically is very hard -- the best I can think of is adding `assert(p != q)` right before this, which will at least give a clean runtime fault rather than something worse.  Checking this at compile time is undecidable in the general case.

Answer (score 4):

The best tool not to detect, but to avoid this in the first place is to use good programming practice. Avoid side-effects and do no more than one write per assignment. There is nothing wrong with

```
*q += 1;
*p = *q;
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression is the same as i=++i. The only tool that can detect it is your head. In C with power comes responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

### Chapter 5 Expressions

#### Point 4:

> Except where noted, the order of evaluation of operands of individual operators and subexpressions of individual expressions, and the order in which side effects take place, is unspecified. ***Between the previous and next sequence point a scalar object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression***. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored. The requirements of this paragraph shall be met for each allowable ordering of the subexpressions of a full expression; otherwise the behavior is undefined.

```
[ Example:
  i = v[i ++];           / / the behavior is undefined
  i = 7 , i++ , i ++;    / / i becomes 9
  i = ++ i + 1;          / / the behavior is undefined 
  i = i + 1;             / / the value of i is incremented
—end example ]
```

As a result this is undefined behavior:

```
int i;
int *p = &i;
int *q = &i;
*p = ++(*q);   // Bad Line
```

In 'Bad Line' the scalar object 'i' is update more than once during the evaluation of the expression. Just because the object 'i' is accessed indirectly does not change the rule.

Comment: Might want to say Chapter 5 of what.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I will give you two guesses.

Comment: thanks very much but I don't want to make two guesses, or any guesses at all for that matter.

Comment: @Kinopiko: The only thing that is ever quoted in answer to a C++ question would be the C++ standard. If there were a discrepancy between the standards I would specify the exact version but since they are all the same it is redundant.

Comment: York: Thanks, I didn't realize either that this was a C++ question or that the only possible thing to quote in an answer to a C++ question would be that.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. The one thing you have highlighted is 'sequence points', to quote from this [site](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/sequence_points.html)

> why you cannot rely on expressions such as:
>   a[i] = i++;
>   because there is no sequence point specified for the assignment, increment or index operators, you don't know when the effect of the increment on i occurs.

And further more, that expression above is similarly the same, so the behaviour is **undefined**, as for tools to track that down, is zero, sure there's [splint](http://www.splint.org) to name one as an example, but it's a C standard, so maybe there's a hidden option in a tool that I have not yet heard of, maybe [Gimpel](http://www.gimpel.com/html/lint90.htm)'s PC Lint or [Riverblade](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html)'s Visual lint might help you although I'll admit it does not mention anything about tracking down undefined behaviour in this regard.

Incidentally, GCC's compiler version 4.3.3 has this option `-Wsequence-point` as part of flagging up warnings..this is on my Slackware 13.0 box...

It just shows, that code may look ok to the naked eye and will compile just fine, but can cause headaches later on, the best way to do it is to have code review that can spot out things a compiler may not pick up on, that is the best weapon of choice!