# Strange "+=" behaviour

Tags: c

What must this code segment return ? 16 16 16 right ?

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int a=2,*f1,*f2;
   f1=f2=&a;
   *f2+=*f1+=a+=2.5;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",a,*f1,*f2);
   return 0;
}
```

strangely, it returns 8 8 8 to me ???? :-(

Comment: Who put you to write that code?!?

Comment: The questioner perhaps wasn't to know, but this is another subtle variant of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Comment: What is that monster? Does your teacher enjoy stabbing good practices in the back? The behavior of that isn't even defined/guaranteed xD

Comment: Yeah, avoiding "knowledge" that doesn't matter is an art :)

Comment: Test your C Skills by Yashwant Kanitkar?

Comment: more or less same.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571301/is-this-code-undefined-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an actual understanding of the issue here try [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com) article on [sequence points](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html).

Comment: Oh! I have never figured that out despite I have had never problems with it, it is always good to know that things are undefined (or unspecified) behaviour. Specially, because in practice, I already realized that some kind of sequence points exists, but didn't know they were documented. Great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

`*f2+=*f1+=a+=2.5;`

Same old Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Prasoon: if, as I am beginning to suspect, you've written a bot to scan the new questions for instances of this, and rapidly alert you to the opportunity to get in quick for loads of points, then you should totally submit it to GCC for use issuing warnings about dodgy code ;-)

Comment: @Steve : Made it CW [No more reps on this one now].

Comment: @Steve: no, probably he is just teaching C to all those guys, and they all listen well at the beginning of the course when he is telling them that SO is a wonderful place to get all the answers, and then part of them slowly fall asleep when he teaches them UB.

Comment: @Steve : And now I have decided not to post answers to these kind of questions.

Comment: @Prasoon: Sorry, I didn't intend it as any kind of criticism. I think it's good that you answered: people need to be told this kind of thing before they spend a lot of time being very wrong about what UB actually is, like you dealt with last time. So you deserve the upvotes you get for doing it. I was just trying to joke that you got to the last couple so quickly. I was reminded of an old colleague who had a program scanning his email for the word "biscuit" (US: "cookie") and popping up an alert on screen.

Comment: @Steve : Its all right Steve `:)` [I noticed the smiley :)]. I think I have posted too many answers for these kind of questions lately so I should probably focus more on other stuffs too. No need to be sorry, its perfectly fine, no hard feelings from my side :)

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined behavior because the value of `a` is modified more than once in that string of assignments.  So what you might expect is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior according to spec 6.5/2 because you modify an object more than once between sequence point:

> Between  the  previous  and  next 
>   sequence  point  an  object  shall 
>   have  its  stored  value modified at
>   most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression.  Furthermore, the prior
>   value shall be read only to determine
>   the value to be stored.

Comment: And because the behavior is undefined, *any* result is possible, whether it appears to make sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's translated to

```
*f2 += 2;
*f1 += 2;
  a += 2.5;
```

and that `+=` is not so transitive as `=`.

Comment: It is essentially the same as "a += a += a += 2.5" and that's pretty much well into nasal demon territory.